# Regex for git tag

Tags: regex

I have this regex (I'm very, very poor on regex, sorry!):

`.*`

It catches every tag I put on git, ex. `3.18.0.1-COLL` or `4.50.1-TEST`

But I need catch only this format:

`n.n.n`

So, for example `3.18.0` or `1.2.3`, 3 digits with 2 points inside. Digits from 0 to 99999.

How can I write that regex?

Answer (score 1):

`^\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}$`

`\d{1,5}` Will match 1 to 5 digits next to each other, `\.` will match a dot literally. Wraping a regex pattern with `^` and `$` will block and preceding and following characters from matching the pattern.

Also [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great tool.

Comment: @JvdV thanks for pointing it out, I forgot to wrap the regex in codeblock.

Comment: No, this matches also "1.2.3-COLL" that I don't want

Comment: @sineverba try ^\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}$ it will block any characters to match before and after the pattern

Comment: @sineverba you may also want to try `(\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5})` to EXTRACT the matching part and discard the rest but it is not the question you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{1,5}
```

`[0-9]` is basically match an number between 0 and 9.

`{1,5}` means to repeat the number matching 1 to 5 times (9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999).

`\.` just checks for the full stop/dot/decimal/point whatever you want to call it.

And here is a visual representation...

[image]

The above image is take from https://www.debuggex.com/ which I found to be a super useful tool when learning regex.

---

You mentioned "Digits from 0 to 99999" however, if you want to match numbers greater than `999999` such as 999999123 you can modify the regex above to...

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Which translates to...

`[0-9]` match an number between 0 and 9.

`+` means repeat the number matching infinite times.

`\.` just checks for the full stop.

Comment: No, this mathces also "1.2.3-COLL" that I don't want

Answer (score 0):

**Pattern**: `^(?:\d{1,5}\.){2}\d{1,5}$`

**Explanation**

1. `^` - Beginning of the string
2. `(?:\d{1,5}\.)` - Captures upto 5 digits (`\d{1,5}`) followed by a period (`\.`)
3. `{2}` - Capture exactly 2 occurrences of the previous group
4. `\d{1,5}` - Captures upto 5 digits
5. `$` - End of the string

**Example**

```
Text        -> 3.18.12345
Regex Match -> 3.18.12345

Text        -> 3.18.12345.1.2-WHATEVER
Regex Match -> no match

Text        -> 3.18
Regex Match -> no match
```

Comment: No, this matches also "1.2.3-COLL" that I don't want

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to only match the string if the string is EXACTLY in `n.n.n` format and it shouldn't match string which contains `n.n.n` in it? If thats the case I think the following should work: `^(?:\d{1,5}\.){2}\d{1,5}$`

Comment: Need to match only 1.2.3 and not 1.2.3-COLL or 1.2.3-TEST or 1.2.3-WHATEVER

Comment: The pattern I mentioned in my last comment does just that. Did you try it? The `^` and `$` marks the start and end of the string. So it will ONLY match 1.2.3 and not 1.2.3-COLL or 1.2.3-TEST or 1.2.3-WHATEVER. I'll update the answer if it works as expected.